# Solving a Sturm-Liouville problem

Tags: sturm-liouville

I want to solve the Sturm-Liouville problem:

$\mathcal{A}u=-u''$

with I.C:

\begin{cases}
u(0)=0\\
u'(L)=0
\end{cases}

where $\mathcal{A}$ is the Sturm-Liuville operator defined on $\mathscr{D}_A:\{u\in C^2([0,L])$.

By reading this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4409164/solving-an-initial-value-problem-pde) from SE , I see that it is practically the same as a PDE. So using the characteristic equation, I obtain:

$u''+Au=0$

$m=\pm\sqrt{-4A}/2=\pm iA$

$u(x)=Be^{iAx}+Ce^{-iAx}$

We rewrite to :

\begin{gather}
u(L)=
\begin{cases}
B\cos Ax\\
iB\sin Ax
\end{cases}
\end{gather}

Since the first conI seedition yields a existence of u at the origin, we can disregard from the cosine solution. We get thus:

\begin{equation}
u(x)=iB\sin Ax
\end{equation}

Using first IC, we have $u(x)=\sin Ax$

Then using the second IC:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
fu'(x)=A\cos Ax\\
u'(L)=A\cos A L\\
0=A\cos A x\\
\cos AL =0\\
A=\big(\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi\big)\frac{1}{L}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

This gives

\begin{equation}
u(x)=\sin \bigg(\big(\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi\big)\frac{x}{L}\bigg)
\end{equation}

What is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you conclude $A=\pi n$ from the first initial condition? $u(x) = iB \sin(A x)$ already fulfills $u(0)=0$ for any $B, A$, no need to fix $B$ or $A$. The second initial condition will aid you to fix $A$ and not $L$ which is part of the data in the problem. $B$ on the other hand is free up to this point.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will correct this.

Comment: @FeedbackLooper, I can't "find L".... is this meant to be as this? Thanks

Comment: $L$ disappears when you evaluate the function at $L$. However, $u$ should be a function of another variable, say $x$, not $L$. $L$ is a constant parameter of the problem.

Comment: Yes, I misinterpreted L as a the variable. But x is still vanishing.

Comment: When you use the second initial condition, you need to use $x=L$. So you solve for $A$ in terms of $L$ and plug that in the expresion for $u(x)$.

Comment: From what you wrote, it should be $u'(L)=0$ not $u'(x)=0$

Comment: Great, thanks! This helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Sturm-Liouville problem is the eigenvalue problem
$$
        -u''(x)=\lambda u(x),\;\;\; 0 \le x \le L
$$
subject to the following endpoint constraints:
$$
      u(0)=0,\;\; u'(L)=0.
$$
The problem is to expand a function $f\in L^2[0,L]$ in terms of the eigenfunction solutions of the above. In your case, you have a regular Sturm-Liouville problem, and the expansion will be a discrete expansion in terms of the eigenfunctions
$$
          e_n(x)=\sin((n+1/2)\pi x/L),\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
It is easy to  verify that $e_n(0)=0$ is satisfied for all $n=1,2,3,\cdots$, and the right endpoint restriction is also satisfied:
$$
   e_n'(L)=\cos((n+1/2)\pi)\{(n+1/2)\pi/L\}=0,\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
The Fourier expansion of $f\in L^2[0,L]$ in terms of these eigenfunctions is given by
$$
     f(x) \sim \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\int_{0}^{L}f(y)e_n(y)dy}{\int_{0}^{L}e_n^2(y)dy}e_n(x).
$$
This Sturm-Liouville eigenfunction expansion is guaranteed to converge to $f$ in the norm of $L^2[0,L]$ even though the series expansion always converges to $0$ at $x=0$

Comment: Is my answer sufficient, though it is more simple than yours? Thanks DISINTEGRATION BY PARTS!

Comment: please send me an email, I have something to ask you.

Comment: @Luthier : I don't have an email address for you.

Comment: if you follow my profile to my homepage, you will see it there under the contact infromation. Here I can't post it.

Answer (score 1):

After you have got $u'(x)=A\cos (Ax)$ you used the second I.C wrong. we know that $u'(L)=0$ so that would give

$$
0=u'(L)=A\cos(AL)\,\Rightarrow\,A=\frac{1}{L}\cdot\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi\cdot n\right)
$$

for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. It implies that $u(x)=\sin\left(\frac{1}{L}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi\cdot n\right)x\right)$

Comment: This I struggle with all the time. Isn't cosx=0 x=n pi/2 ? Why adding $\pi n$ when it is already given in $n\pi/2$?

Comment: No, for example $\cos(\pi)=-1$ and $\cos(0)=1$. If you know that $\sin(x)=0$ implies $x=\pi\cdot k$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, remember that $\cos(x)$ is just a shift of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ units of $\sin(x)$ to the left.

Comment: OK, so I add npi to what ever value that gives 0, in this case.

Comment: Yes, Exactly :)

Comment: One thing, should it be AsinAx? I couldn't find a reason to keep A in front of it, so I got sinAx

Comment: No, it is my mistake. I will edit the answer.